# Disable a select field when selecting more than one element form another select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML page contains 3 multiple select fields (boostrap dropdown component):

```
<select class="form-control bootstrap-select"
        data-style="alpha-grey-300 pt-5 pb-5 pl-10 text-size-mini" multiple
        id="associated.persons" data-live-search="true">
</select>
<select class="bootstrap-select"
        data-style="alpha-grey-300 pt-5 pb-5 pl-10 text-size-mini" multiple
        id="leave.interim.substitutes" data-live-search="true">
</select>
<select class="bootstrap-select"
        data-style="alpha-grey-300 pt-5 pb-5 pl-10 text-size-mini" multiple
        id="leave.interim.validators" data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

I want to disable the last 2 select fields ("leave.interim.substitutes" and "leave.interim.validators") when more than one element is selected from the first select field ("associated.persons"). What's the best way to do that using jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#associated.persons").change(function(){
    $("#leave.interim.substitutes, #leave.interim.validators").prop("disabled", ($(":selected", this).length == 1));
})
```

`$("#associated.persons").change` initiates a listener for every time a new set of selection is made in `#associated.persons` (in other words, whenever there is a new value, the function inside will trigger.)

`$("#leave.interim.substitutes, #leave.interim.validators")` selects the two elements of interest. `.prop("disabled", boolean)` sets the disabled property of the two elements. If `true`, add a `disabled=true` If `false`, it should remove the `disabled` attribute.

This boolean is determined by `($(":selected", this).length == 1)`, a conditional statement which returns true or false. `this` refers to the `#associated.persons` element and `:selected` refers to any selected option inside it. `.length` since multiple elements in jQuery is simply an array.

So `($(":selected", this).length == 1)` means that if jQuery selects just 1 element, (that element being the `:selected` option),  then return true. Otherwise, return false.

I placed the conditional inside to reduce lines, but it should still be fairly readable.

Comment: Please provide more detail in your answer. How/why would this code fix the issue?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Happy,  masters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get length of selected items:
var count = $("#yourSelect :selected").length;

And disabled

```
if (count > 1) {
            $('#yourSelect').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#yourSelect').attr('disabled', true);
        }
```